# What PHP, Xdebug and Eclipse configurations work on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, eclipse, xdebug

I have been mucking around for days, trying to find the right combination that lets me debug with breakpoints and variable viewing, in Eclipse, without crashing Apache.

- PHP 5.3? PHP 5.2?
- Eclipse Helios? Eclipse Galileo? One or the other with certain versions of xdebug or php? Or do I really need to use NetBeans or something else?
- Is my 64 bit OS the problem? Do need specific 64bit versions of PHP, Eclipse or Xdebug to work on Windows 7 64?
- Any special xdebug config options and tricks that I need in php.ini? Like turning off xdebug.profiler_enable or not using quotes around my zend_extension path to the xdebug dll?
- A Vhosts issue?
- Scrap the whole thing and go back to Win XP or Ubuntu?

Here's what I've already been reading:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509245/so-eclipse-and-xdebug-walk-into-a-bar-and-then-my-apache-server-dies/4602473
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206788/why-does-xdebug-crash-apache-on-every-xampp-install-ive-tried
- http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=459
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312951#c8
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799936/xdebug-for-php-5-2-on-windows-7-64bit
- and so and so on... SO, xdebug bug tracker, eclipse bugzilla, etc, etc

Basically what would be great is if folks could post their working (i.e. debugging with breakpoints and local variable viewing in Eclipse) Win7 64bit configurations, including:

- PHP version (5.3.1, 5.2.11, etc)
- Xdebug dll (2.1.0-5.3-vc6, etc)
- Xdebug php.ini config (zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll", etc)
- Apache version (2.2.14, etc)
- Eclipse version
- Anything else important? The "secret ingredient"?

Thanks! I miss my debugger since I got a new laptop with Win 7! Sadly it looks like some of the drivers (switchable graphics, multi-touch pad, etc) on my lappy don't work right with Ubuntu yet, so I feel a bit trapped on Win :( I know I will figure something out eventually, but I've been at this trial-and-error game a while and am seeking some guidance.

(Originally posted on StackOverflow here, but moved to SuperUser:)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628215/what-php-xdebug-and-eclipse-configurations-work-on-windows-7-64-bit

Comment: For what it's worth, 4 years later (!), I develop in a Vagrant box now (using VirtualBox), so I run PHP and Xdebug in a native Linux environment. Xdebug still works for step-through debugging in my IDE (PHPStorm), and even with console debugging. I would suggest anyone landing on this question Google "vagrant" and save yourself (some of) the "WAMP" setup headaches.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2370 videos on how to get XDebug working on youtube. I have been through 50 of them for Luna Eclipse. I finally gave up and switched to PhpStorm. Best Decision ever. The xdebug stuff is relatively easy on storm, and the rest of the app is wonderful. I have installed XDebug with eclipse a dozen times, got it working with keplar and the others eventually (never luna), but it always took forever, always accompanied by cursing and swearing a blue streak. You are way better off to dump eclipse and go to something else. Its a great product but the constant XDebug hassles make it a loosing proposition.

Comment: Now that's it's 4 years later, I would note that I'm having a much better time developing in Vagrant boxes. PHP and Xdebug work much better on Linux, and it mirrors or production environment. Also, I switched to PHPStorm for my IDE.